# post the input values to mail and show the details

Tags: php, jquery, html, phpmailer

I have tried a lot for the post of following input which is come from previous `orderonline.php` page but the problem is that i want to post all values such as name their quantity and total price on Email via `phpmailer()` function.

Problem is that on email only the quantity is get displayed
the code is as follows:

```js
<script>
     jQuery('.plus').click(function() {
     var qut = jQuery(this).prev().val();
     var plus = (parseInt(qut) + 1);
     jQuery(this).prev().val(plus);
     if (plus > parseInt(0)) {
    var price = jQuery(this).prev().data('price');
    jQuery(this).parent().next().html(parseInt(plus) * parseInt(price));
     } else {
              jQuery(this).parent().next().html(price);
            }
     var price = [];
     var p = 0;
    jQuery('.finalprice').each(function() {
    p = (parseInt(p) + parseInt(jQuery(this).html()));});
    jQuery('.totalprice').html(p);});
    jQuery('.minus').click(function() {
     var qut = jQuery(this).next().val();
     var plus = (parseInt(qut) - 1);
          if (plus > parseInt(0)) {
          jQuery(this).next().val(plus);
          var price = jQuery(this).next().data('price');
   jQuery(this).parent().next().html(parseInt(plus) * parseInt(price));
   } else { jQuery(this).parent().next().html(price);}
 var p = 0;
 jQuery('.finalprice').each(function() {
  p = (parseInt(p) + parseInt(jQuery(this).html()));});
  jQuery('.totalprice').html(p);});
</script>


`<form action="confirm.php" method="post">`
` <?php`
`   $i=0;`
`   if(isset($_POST['chk'])){`
`    foreach($_POST['chk'] as $key=>$value){`
`    echo "<tr><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"prdct[".$i."]\" readonly style=\"border:none;width:auto;\" value=\"".$_POST['nam'][$key]."\"></td>";`
`    echo "<td><span class=\"minus\" style=\"font-size:17px!important;\">-</span>";`
`    echo "<input class=\"Quantity\"  style=\"margin:1px;text-align:center\" size=\"3\" type=\"text\" name=\"quantity[".$i."]\" data-price=\"".$value."\" value=\"1\"><span class=\"plus\"style=\"font-size:17px!important;\">+ </span> </td>";`
`     echo "<td class=\"finalprice\">".$value."</td></tr>";`
`          }`
`      }    `
`    ?>`
```

The respected Email should look like this image:

[image: Email image]

Comment: when I looked into image attached with this question there only quantity not displaying and you are saying that "Problem is that on email only the quantity is get displayed the code". Please clear your question first..

Comment: sir i have inserted following code in confirm.php but it shows only value is 2 not name or totalprice

Comment: you need to beutify your before posting..

Comment: `$a=$_POST['prdct'];`
` foreach ($a as $k=>$qt) {`
`$mail->Body ="<body>`
`<div style=\"width:600p;\">`
`       <center><h3>Order Information</h3></center>`
`<hr color=\"#000000\" style=\"height:3px;\" />`
`<table width=\"400\">`
`<tr class=\"titles\">`
`<td >Menu Name</td>`
`<td >Quantity</td>`
`<td>Price</td></tr>`
`<tr><td>". $k."</td> `
`<td> ".$k['quantity'][$qt]."</td>`
`<td>".$k."</td></tr></table>}`